# Sonarqube or sonarqube.runner.MSbuild missing a project/related dll

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I had a main project with multiple projects and one of them, a WCF.dll, the sonarqube6.4 don't like or something happened that the dll don't appear at the project at sonarqube.

The runner as i could see, analyze the source-code correctly, but when it finished the sonarqube don't show the information:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild "FILE_MAINTENANCE.sln"

Output:

> D:\Desarrollo\Personales\FileMaintenance\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.csproj"
>   (Rebuild target) (8) ->   WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.cs(172,18):
>   warning CS0219: The variable 'bolFnResult' is assigned but its value
>   is never used
>   [D:\Desarrollo\Personales\FileMaintenance\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.csproj]
>   WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_THREADING.cs(264,33): warning CS0472: The
>   result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int'
>   is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'
>   [D:\Desarrollo\Personales\FileMaintenance\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.csproj]
>   WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_THREADING.cs(273,33): warning CS0472: The
>   result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int'
>   is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'
>   [D:\Desarrollo\Personales\FileMaintenance\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.csproj]
>   WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_THREADING.cs(281,33): warning CS0472: The
>   result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int'
>   is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'
>   [D:\Desarrollo\Personales\FileMaintenance\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.csproj]
>   WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.cs(820,23): warning CS0219: The
>   variable 'intID' is assigned but its value is never used
>   [D:\Desarrollo\Personales\FileMaintenance\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.csproj]
>   WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_COPY_THREADING.cs(201,42): warning CS0168: The
>   variable 'ex' is declared but never used
>   [D:\Desarrollo\Personales\FileMaintenance\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY\WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_LIBRARY.csproj]
>   WIS_WCF_FILEMAINTENANCE_COPY_THREADING.cs(905,41): warning CS0168: The
>   variable 'tae' is declared but never used [D:\Desarrollo\Personales\F

Sonarqube website:
[image: Sonarqube6.4 website]

VisualStudio2015:
[image: Sonarqube and VS2015]

What could be happend? 
There is a property that i missed that make the project to be ignored?

Thank you so much in advance.

P.S: ah sorry, i forgot one thing more i open the single project "sln" from the dll and the sonarqube show perfectly the info, but when the project is attached to the main, always was ignored.

Luis.

Comment: here you are:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68337028/SonarRunerMSBuild.zip

Comment: Have you find anything? i'm a little curious...